# Spark structured streaming metrics are confusing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, jmx

I start a structured streaming(spark 3.1.2) which writes to kafka (1 driver, 5 executor on K8s)

```
dataFrame
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-host:9092")
      .option("topic", "my-topic")
```

By the time all the inputs are processed the Kafka topic 'my-topic' consists 38087 new messages. So 38087 rows were written into Kafka.
Metrics are written to the ConsoleSink and on the SparkUI.

**Now let's see the actual Spark metrics:**

```
spark.streaming.states-rowsTotal: 3600  (Gauge)
spark.streaming.states-rowsUpdated: 0   (Gauge)
executor.recordsWritten:  0             (Counter)
```

Makes no sense...

**Now lets check all the ConsoleSink entries:**

```
spark.streaming.states-rowsTotal: 41687,3600, 3600...n
spark.streaming.states-rowsUpdated: 41687,0,0...n
executor.recordsWritten:  0...n
```

As you can see rowsTotal was 41687 at first since then it is 3600. RecordsWritten is still 0.

But if I check recordsWritten on the SparkUi:

```
driver-ip/api/v1/app-id/stages/stage-id
```

For all the stage-id there are 400piece of entries with 0 value, except for one which has the value of 41687

**Magic math:** If I perform x=41687-3600 then I get 38087 which is the number of new rows in Kafka. What the heck is going on?

**So the questions are:**

1. what rowsTotal,rowsUpdated represent and why are they Guage types?
2. what recordsWritten represents?
3. Why the value of recordsWritten in a Sink and on SparkUI are different?
4. What is the reason behind the magis substraction above? Makes no sense at all
5. How to get/create a single metric which shows the total number of rows written into Kafka

Answer (score 1):

`spark.streaming.states-rowsTotal` means the number of rows in state store if you used some stateful operators. It has no relations with output records.

The sum of `executor.recordsWritten` for all executors should return total records writen to sink. But unforuntately, most streaming sink doesn't correctly updates this metrics(at least for console, kafka sink).

One workaround I can think of is:

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.persist()
  batchDF.count()  // write count to some where
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // write into kafka
  batchDF.unpersist()
}
```